# Jquery $.post not working mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having trouble posting my formdata back to the controller. I'm trying to implement a wizard in a MVC4 application, the wizard is based on a sample project from Nadeem Afana (http://afana.me/post/create-wizard-in-aspnet-mvc-3.aspx).
I have downloaded the sample project and it's working great. In my project the code is also working fine except for one thing, the 'post' is not working (while the submit later IS working).

I've isolated the variables, and they look fine to me if I look at them in the debugger in Firefox

```
var data = $("form").serialize();
var url = '@Url.Action("Confirm", "Product")';

$.post(url, data, function (r)
{
    // inject response in confirmation step
    $(".wizard-step.confirm").html(r);
});
```

However, the action on the specified controller isn't begin called (I've put a breakpoint on it)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Confirm(ProductModel model)
{
   // my code ...
   return PartialView(model);
}
```

I have also tried

```
$.post("/Product/Confirm", $("form").serialize(), function (r)
```

using the URL instead of @Url.Action ... no change.

For the life of me I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong or what it is I'm missing, I've been googling searching trying the whole afternoon.

Comment: What happens? What do you see in the console?

Comment: Don't you have another action with other method signature?

Comment: @SLaks: I'm not sure what you mean by console, but when I look in FireFox debugger and set breakpoint on the $.post line and then click (Step-Out) I can see it continue at the last } of the event. It do not get an error or exception (or so it would seem)

Comment: @gustavodidomenico: I've tried calling other actions, even one with an empty signature [HttpPost] public ActionResult JurTest(), but the action doesn't get called.

Comment: @SLaks: I guess you mean the FF-error console. I just found it. I do see one error-message, not sure if it's the cause :

Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true. http://localhost/ocm/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js line: 4043

Comment: Please post an example of the "final" html rendered in your form, and also the c# of your ProductModel

Comment: Are you sure your URL shouldn't be $.post("/ocm/Product/Confirm", $("form").serialize(), function (r). Looks like you are running in a virtual directory to me. /Product/Confirm points to localhost/Product/Confirm

Comment: Could you use fiddler or any developer toolbar and post the http response?

Comment: @Jurjen Are you receiving that console error when the page loads or when you try to submit your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) and then use it to see exactly what request is being made (if any) and why it's failing. Honestly in my experience trying to fix Ajax issues without some sort of tool like Fiddler is practically impossible and certainly a big time sync...

Comment: After installing Fiddler it turns out that /Products/Confirm returns a 404 error (action not found). After changing the URL to the complete path http://localhost/ocm/Products/Confirm it worked !!

Thanks for helping me out everyone !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the full notation of the ajax call in case some default is messing you up?

```
mydata = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
  url: '/Product/Confirm',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: mydata,
  success: function() {
    $(".wizard-step.confirm").html(r);
});
```

EDIT 1:

Error handling

```
error: function(response, status, error) {
  alert(error);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't seem to make a difference, the action is not called. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I can see it hitting that part of the javascript code in the debugger but it subsequently seems to skip it ...

Comment: Try adding an error option and see what is returned.  I will edit an example in to my answer

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried inserting the snippet into my script but then the script didn't execute at all so I ended up using a try/catch around the call, but no error was 'caught', it still skips to the end of the code block, not mentioning anything.

Comment: try using a debugger like firebug or chrome developer tools and step through the code line by line.  When it gets to the ajax call it will go line by line and then suddenly jump on one of them.  The one it jumps on is the one with the error.  Let me know which line it is and I will try and help.

Comment: Thanks, I was already using the debugger in FireFox... I've just installed Fiddler and it turns out it cannot find the controller/action, after changing it (on my dev-machine) to http://localhost/ocm/product/confirm it actually does work. not sure why, but it does ! Now I have to find a way to get around this, I don't like hardcoding the full URL as it might change in the production environment.

thanks for all your help.

Comment: yes no problem.  Most likely your issue lies in how your routing is set up in MVC. I would check there first.